# Kivy: Instance of 'XXXX' has no 'bind' member

Tags: python, exception, kivy, bind

I am writing a program in Kivy, and whenever I am trying to bind a function to a Button or any other widget I get the following problem from pylint: "Instance of 'Button' has no 'bind' member" and the lines turn red. I am completely new to Kivy and this really bugs me.

The program works perfect when I execute it, and the compiler does not seem to have any problem with my bindings. What have I done wrong? Am I missing an import or anything, or is there something wrong with my environment?

Attached you find a code snippet I wrote as an example.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        button = Button(text='Hello from Kivy',
                        size_hint=(.5, .5),
                        pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5})
        button.bind(on_press=self.on_press_button)

        return button

    def on_press_button(self, instance):
        print('You pressed the button!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MainApp()
    app.run()
```

Comment: A little bit late to the party but for perhaps for people reading in the future: if you're using pylint and you get this warning, add kivy to the package whitelist as follows in your .pylintrc file: `extension-pkg-whitelist=kivy`

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that whatever linter you are using is not able to find the bind method because it comes from cython code. You need to configure it differently (if possible), or use a different linter.

Comment: Ok, I am using pylint, how do you mean that I should configure it? Edit: I switched to mypy and it worked. Thanks!